# Is $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ a continuous function?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Rational functions are continuous in its domain. Our function is rational function with domain $\mathbb{R} - \{0 \}$. So it must be continuous in its domain.

But one of my friend argues that $f$ does not have limit at $0$ (which is a limit point of domain of $f$) so we can't say it is continuous. Which argument is correct ?

Answer (score 9):

Your argument is correct. $0$ is not in the domain of $f$. Thats all !

Answer (score 4):

The point $x=0$ is not in the domain $\mathbb R \backslash \{0\}$, so the limit $x \to 0$ is irrelevant.

Would your friend say that $\displaystyle{f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}}$, with domain $\mathbb R$, is discontinuous because $f(x)$ is not defined when $x=\pm \, i$ ?

**Interesting fact:** If we use the [protectively extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line) as the domain (and range), then all irreducible [rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function#Definitions) are continuous for all inputs.

Comment: "Interesting fact"  So, I take it that {x:|\infty - x| < e} = {x:|x| > 1/e}?

Comment: @fleablood https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line#Continuity

Comment: But $i$ and $-i$ are not limit points of domain of $f$ . So my friend can't  discuss limit at these points. isn't it ?

Answer (score 3):

By definition, $f$ is continuous if it's continuous at every point of its domain. Therefore $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is indeed continuous. At the same time, $f$ is not continuous at $0$, because it's not even defined there. However, $0$ is not a point in the domain of $f$, so it isn't taken into account when talking about the continuity of $f$. That $0$ is a limit point of the domain doesn't matter.

Comment: The no limit argument just shows that $f$ cannot be defined in $0$ to make it a continuous function on all of $\mathbb{R}$.